# Query filter todays date

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to query db to only show leads that have been inserted on todays data. Am I going to use Where Clause?

**Query:**

`SELECT * FROM leads WHERE marketer <>  'Tommy'`

**Database Table**

```
Column  Type    Null    Default Comments

id  int(10) No       
timestamp   timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    
marketer    varchar(25) Yes     NULL     
name    varchar(100)    Yes     NULL     
type    varchar(25) Yes     NULL     
phone   varchar(12) Yes     NULL     
email   varchar(50) Yes     NULL     
fax varchar(12) Yes     NULL     
description varchar(500)    Yes     NULL     
locality    varchar(35) Yes     NULL     
state   varchar(25) Yes     NULL     
zip varchar(5)  Yes     NULL     
latlng  varchar(256)    Yes     NULL     
facility    varchar(100)    Yes     NULL     
marketer_id int(11) No
```

Comment: Do you have date field in your database. Show the database table fields and some sample data

Comment: of course you have to use where condition.

Comment: @StevenRostorfer add that to question

Comment: timestamp is the date field in my database.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table where DATE(date)=CURDATE()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM leads WHERE marketer <>  'Tommy' AND DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE();
```

This will give you today's record where marketer is not Tommy

Answer (score 0):

If the date column is index, this may useful

```
SELECT * FROM leads 
WHERE 
marketer <>  'Tommy' 
and `timestamp` > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),interval -1 day) 
and `timestamp` < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),interval 1 day) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the current day's data,

```
    $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE marketer <> 'Tommy' AND DATE(timestamp) = $todays_date"
```

This should work, sanitize your inputs where necessary and consider varying timezones.